# Is it better to use Views in SQL or should i just use queries in my C# Code

Tags: c#, mysql, view

I gonna write a new Program,
is it better to store my Queries in Views and call them from my C# Code.

Or should i Just execute all SQL queries in my Code.

Which is better for the Performance.

Comment: You still need to query a view. More to the point: profile it if you are concerned and see for yourself. We can't help you do that.

Comment: Its better to store your queries as a Stored Procedure, A view is completely different (as some developer / Sql Admin) use this for a search functionality or a grid view, with in their app.
I prefer using Stored Procs, as i believe i can just have singular files for each action add/update, delete, select, Views, with all the queries respectively. 
In terms of performance only you will be able to tell depending on your queries and the way you access your database.

Comment: I gonna use queries for simple tasks and Views when i have to connect like 5 tables which is the case in my project. thank you :*

Comment: See also this: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd171921(v=sql.100).aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From a performance point of view there is no difference between running a query from C# and accessing a view that is based on the same query; the only difference would be if the view that you are accessing has indexes on it and thus runs faster than your ad-hoc query.

As a good practice is best to use SQL View when extracting data from multiple tables through joins as putting the whole SQL code in C# would look messy and might be more prone to errors.

There are a lot of things to be considered when undertaking this:
1. volume of data - indexed views
2. number of tables involved
3. database structure dynamic - how often you change tables

have fun!